# how to draw a google chart from angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

I'm trying to draw some charts inside a ng-repeat loop. I thought a nice way to do that would be using angular directives, however I can't seem to make them work. This is what I have so far:

**code:**

```
myApp.directive("plotPie", function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            tabledata: "="
        },
        link: function ($scope, element) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
            data.addColumn('number', 'data');
            data.addRows(tabledata);
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(element);
            chart.draw(data);
        },
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div plot-pie tabledata="mydata" width="70%">
```

Comment: Just a guess (not an educated guess) but shouldn't it be `<div class="plotPie" tabledata="mydata" width=70%">` instead of just plopping `plot-pie` in the middle?

Comment: @NealC only if the returned object contains a `restrict : 'C'` attribute, but that's not the case here.

Comment: you seem to be missing a closing tag for the div in the html, not sure if that has anything to do with it

Comment: @MariusP. It shouldn't. not when there is only one `div`. Although it's good practice to always close it. P.S the "." on your name annoyed me ;P

Answer (score 0):

You mistaken to use isolated `scope` variable should be `scope.tabledata`

Instead of

```
data.addRows(tabledata);
```

Use

```
data.addRows(scope.tabledata);
```